# Concat a variable to a function name

Tags: php

How can I concatenate a variable containing a string to a function name? I tried all methods, but none worked for me.

```
$mode = 'Remove';

friend.$mode.($mode);

function friendRemove() {

}
```

Comment: Start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func` https://www.php.net/call_user_func like this:

```
$mode = 'Remove';
call_user_func('friend'.$mode, $p1, $p2, ...);

function friendRemove($p1, $p2, ...) {}
```

Also there is `call_user_func_array` function which is very useful too https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array

Comment: also `$t = "friend".$mode;$t();`

Comment: That a nice one, but can call_user_func return boolean if I did `if(call_user_func('freind'.$mode, $p1)) { echo 'Ok'} else { echo 'Error'}` Because that's what I do when calling a function without the `call_user_func`.

Comment: @Norman sure you can - please read manual "Returns the return value of the callback, or FALSE on error.".

Answer (score 2):

```
$function_name = 'friendRemove';
// or
$mode = 'Remove';
$function_name = 'friend' . $mode;

$function_name();
```